# Fetch the contents of a table row using javascript when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic table and in one of the attributes of that table I have edit link, I want to fetch the data adjacent to that link if that link is clicked.

[image]

For example if I click Edit on line number 2, I should be able to retrieve Demo User, demouser, demo@demo.com and User using javascript.

Comment: Please provide some demo of your implementation, so we can help. Sadly a screenshot isn't enough.

Comment: What implementation?

Comment: You can use id or other custom attribute

Comment: @VaheYavrumian But how to fetch the adjacent Id to that edit link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to access the *row* and then find elements inside that row:

```
$('.your-link').click(function () {
    const row = $(this).closest('tr');
    const whatever = row.find('.whatever').text();
})
```